# Parsing XML with simplexml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Hi im trying to parse XML with simplexml. The problem is i cannot access atributtes, any ideas why?

PHP code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($source);
foreach($xml->children() as $node) {
     foreach ($node->AttrList->attributes() as $attribute) {
          print_r ($attribute);
     }
}
```

Piece of XML:

```
<ProductCatalog>
  <Product>
    <ProductCode>ST905003FND2E1-RK</ProductCode>
    <Vendor>SEAGATE</Vendor>
    <ProductType>HDD External</ProductType>
    <ProductCategory>Cietie diski</ProductCategory>
    <ProductDescription>HDD External SEAGATE FreeAgent Go 5400.2 (2.5",500GB,8MB cache,USB 2.0,FreeAgent software) Black</ProductDescription>
    <Image>https://www.it4profit.com/catalogimg/wic/1/ST905003FND2E1-RK</Image>
    <ProductCard>https://content.it4profit.com/itshop/itemcard_cs.jsp?ITEM=90728055033221913&amp;THEME=asbis&amp;LANG=lv</ProductCard>
    <AttrList>
      <element Name="Device Location" Value="External"/>
      <element Name="Hard Drive Type" Value="Portable"/>
      <element Name="Form Factor" Value="2.5&quot;"/>
      <element Name="Storage Capacity" Value="500000 MB"/>
      <element Name="Supports Data Channel" Value="USB 2.0"/>
      <element Name="Installed Cache Memory Storage Capacity" Value="8 MB"/>
      <element Name="Sector Capacity" Value="512 B"/>
      <element Name="Rotational Speed" Value="5400 rpm"/>
      <element Name="External Data Bit Rate" Value="480 Mbps (Max)"/>
      <element Name="USB2.0  Interface Quantity" Value="1"/>
      <element Name="Platform Compability" Value="PC"/>
      <element Name="Software Included" Value="FreeAgent software"/>
      <element Name="Requires Operating System" Value="Microsoft Windows XP, Microsoft Windows Vista"/>
      <element Name="Requires Peripheral Devices" Value="USB 2.0 port"/>
      <element Name="Cable Included" Value="USB Cable"/>
      <element Name="External Color" Value="Black"/>
      <element Name="Case Material" Value="Plastic"/>
      <element Name="Depth" Value="146.1 mm"/>
      <element Name="Height" Value="177.8 mm"/>
      <element Name="Width" Value="50.8 mm"/>
      <element Name="Nominal Weight" Value="0.3 kg"/>
      <element Name="Warranty Products returnable" Value="Yes"/>
      <element Name="Warranty Term (month)" Value="60 month"/>
      <element Name="Warranty validation Criteria" Value="Serial Number"/>
      <element Name="Box Depth (mm)" Value="196 mm"/>
      <element Name="Box Height (mm)" Value="501 mm"/>
      <element Name="Box Weight Brutto (kg)" Value="4 kg"/>
      <element Name="Box Width (mm)" Value="297 mm"/>
      <element Name="Pack Depth (mm)" Value="178 mm"/>
      <element Name="Pack Height (mm)" Value="178 mm"/>
      <element Name="Pack Weight Brutto (kg)" Value="0.57 kg"/>
      <element Name="Pack Width (mm)" Value="89 mm"/>
      <element Name="Packs in Box" Value="6"/>
      <element Name="Pieces in pack" Value="1"/>
      <element Name="EAN Code" Value="7636490016813"/>
    </AttrList>
    <MarketingInfo>
      <element>The ultimate portable storage solution with the world㠔s first hard drive docking station for easy access to all your stuff. Sleek, ultra-thin design that㠔s as stylish as it is striking. &lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt; &lt;ul&gt;&#13;
&lt;li&gt;Store photos, music, and other files&#13;
&lt;li&gt;Carry your data anywhere you want&#13;
&lt;li&gt;Sync data between computers&#13;
&lt;li&gt;Back up files using the optional dock&#13;
&lt;/ul&gt;</element>
    </MarketingInfo>
    <Images>
      <Image>https://content.it4profit.com/pimg/s/resize/160x160x160x160/90818105858024672.jpg</Image>
      <Image>https://content.it4profit.com/pimg/s/resize/400x300x400x300/90818105819015057.jpg</Image>
      <Image>https://content.it4profit.com/pimg/s/resize/200x150x200x150/90818105848608387.jpg</Image>
      <Image>https://content.it4profit.com/pimg/s/resize/75x56x75x56/90818105909870954.jpg</Image>
      <Image>https://content.it4profit.com/pimg/s/resize/362x362x362x362/90818105833910289.jpg</Image>
      <Image>https://content.it4profit.com/pimg/s/resize/260x195x260x195/90818105841219714.jpg</Image>
    </Images>
  </Product>
</ProductCatalog>
```

Comment: AttrList doesn't have any attributes, it's element that has the attributes

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, but 
foreach ($node->AttrList->element->attributes() as $attribute) doesn't work too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not displaying anything because the `<AttrList>` node doesn't have any attributes.

Did you mean?

```
foreach($xml->children() as $node) {
     foreach ($node->AttrList->children() as $child) {
        foreach($child->attributes() as $attribute) {
            echo $attribute->getName() , " - " , $attribute , "\n";
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you have forgot the "element" child. 
so i tested the code below which works for me.
I converted some child parts to arrays, because i had some problems with simplexml parsed objects only.

```
foreach ($xml->children() as $node) {
    $attr_list = (array) $node->AttrList;
    $elements = ($attr_list['element']);
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $element = (array) $element;
        print_r($element['@attributes']);
    }
}
```